# How to find and replace multiple queries at a time

Tags: regex, text, replace, find, editor

Is there any text editor that supports multiple regular expression find and replace queries?
I am already using Dreamweaver and tried some tips to run multiple find and replace queries, but it didn't succeed for regular expression.
If you know a way to run multiple find and replace queries at a time for regular expression, it would be great.
If you know a good software that is compatible with Dreamweaver regex, also please mention!
I mean by "multiple queries" "multiple words" with "multiple replaces" not importantly "multiple files"!

Comment: What about `sed` , `awk` ? Do you have `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: what are sed and awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

Here is how you do it in EditPadPro.

1. Hit Ctrl + Sh + F to open the Search / Replace panel
2. Type your Search and Replace terms
3. At the top right of the search panel, click the pull-down on the Favorite searches menu. Add your search, give it a nickname.
4. Repeat step 3 until you have all the searches you want.
5. Top menu: Macros, Record Macro, give it a name.
6. Click the Favorite searches pulldown, select the first pattern you want to execute
7. Hit Replace All.
8. Repeat 6 and 7 until you have all the replacement regexes you want for the sequence.
9. Macros, Stop recording.
10. Whenever you want to do your sequence of replacements, pull it by name under the Macros menu.

You can get an [EPP trial here](http://www.editpadpro.com/download.html#trial). I use it because of its potent regex flavor (it's the same developer as RegexBuddy).

Comment: For reference, Notepad++ uses PCRE now.  :)

Comment: Yeah, i thought the same til recently.  Then i'd offhand mentioned how much PCRE beats the pants off N++'s crappy DIY regex support, and someone enlightened me.  Turns out i just needed to upgrade.  :)

Comment: thanks for this great recommendation, but do you have any idea to edit macros as it takes me long time to record from the beginning if something is edited in my queries?

Comment: @user3503851 Sure, you can edit the regex in the macro instead. Macros / Organize Macros, then choose Export Macro. Then hit Ctrl + O to open the macro. At that stage you can edit the regex straight in that file, and import it without re-recording. Note that I'm not an EPP expert, the help file under Help / Contents / Macros can tell you much more.

Answer (score 1):

[TextDistil](http://www.textdistil.com/) is a utility intended to let you set up pipelines of regular expressions (similar to as described above for EPP) allowing you to replace text, remove lines or perform other manipulations such as timestamp adjustment.  Full disclosure - I'm the author. :-)

Comment: Answers that boil down to "try this tool" are frowned upon here at SO, but that one promises to be very useful, and I had never of it before, so I'll give you a pass... *this* time. :P

Comment: Thanks Alan.  Is there any kind of guideline on this available?  Clearly I want to stay on the right side of the 'helpful answer vs 'tiresome spam' line.  Should I be asking this question in the meta section?

Comment: Your software sounds very interesting Neil, will give it a try.